# Como eu pego o sql que a linq gera pelo debug do VS2013

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013, expressões-lambda

Como eu pego o sql que a linq gera pelo debug do VS2013? Como eu faço isso?

Fiz assim e não deu certo

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreUn(string _uf, string _cidade, string _un)
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var _listaUnidade = (
                                   from r in db.Ruptura
                                   join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                   join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                                   where r.IDMotivo != 6
                                   group r by new { a.Unidade_Negocio, r.IDMotivo } into gr
                                   select new MontaArvoreAcao
                                   {
                                       IDMotivo = gr.Key.IDMotivo,
                                       Unidade_Negocio = gr.Key.Unidade_Negocio,
                                       Somatorio = gr.Count()
                                   }
                                 ).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);

            if (_un != "" && _un != null)
            {
                _listaUnidade = _listaUnidade.Where(u => u.Unidade_Negocio == _un).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.Unidade_Negocio);
            }

            var query = _listaUnidade.ToString();**==> Aqui não deu certo**

            return _listaUnidade.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Estou como a mesma dúvida e realmente, a resposta dada abaixo não funciona! Infelizmente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você fizer o select usando linq, o resultado será do tipo `DbQuery<T>`. O metodo `.ToString()` dessa classe é [sobrescrito para exibir o comando SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696144(v=vs.113).aspx), então basta chama-lo:

```
var query = from foo in db.foo
            select foo;
var sqlGerado = query.ToString();
```

Comment: não deu certo. Não veio o sql gerado. Foi isso que veio: System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao,System.Int32]

Comment: Você poderia postar partes relevantes do código para que possamos ajuda-lo? Esse método que eu descrevi sempre funcionou para mim, então creio que seu problema seja um pouco mais específico.

Comment: Fiz uma edição do meu método e a tentativa de pegar o sql gerado.

Comment: @pnet Está explicado o motivo. Sua query é executada quando você chama o `.ToList()` (Não sei se o `.Distinct()` causa esse efeito, me corrijam se eu estiver errado). Nesse momento seu objeto deixa de ser um `DbQuery`. Se quiser ver o comando SQL gerado pela query, armazene o que está entre parenteses em uma variável, sem de chamar os métodos `.Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo)`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado.